# Constructing graph with a given number of isomorphisms.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, automorphism-group

Given a graph order of $4n$ for positive $n$, find graphs with $4^n (2n)!$  and $2(2n-1)!^2$ automorphisms. I already have graphs for the first, but haven't had any luck on the other one.

I figured that it suffices to find a graph of order $2m$ with $2(m-1)!^2$ automorphisms, because $4n=2\cdot 2m$. I got the first one by guessing some well known graphs, but that doesn't seem to be working too well for the second.

I'm not necessarily looking for a solution. More so a hint or possible ideas for graphs to look at.

Comment: How many automorphisms does the graph $K_{m,m}-e$ (remove one edge from a complete bipartite graph $K_{m,m}$) have?

Comment: In other words (taking the complement) how many automorphisms does $2K_m+e$ have? I.e., take two disjoint copies of $K_m$ with one edge between them.